# How do I simulate an image texture being spray painted onto a model

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, masking

Basically I have a facebuilder model of a head with an image texture. I want to have the shot start with the model being blank and simulate the texture being sprayed onto the model. I've looked around and can't find any tutorials on this, or even any clue as to whether or not its even possible.

I'm totally open to a cheat, like some way of masking the image texture and having it reveal or something, I just don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Do a search for dynamic paint. That is how you would be able to do this in blender.

Answer (score 1):

Blender Guru has a great tutorial on using dynamic paint.
https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-realistic-rain

Using this technique you could make a particle system that looks like spray paint using it as a brush you can reveal a graphic wherever your particle system touches.